# Perl pattern matching where we print all matching parts, but only the matching parts (not the rest)

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep, pattern-matching

I am looking for a solution to do this in Perl.

Example:
If my string is:

```
my $content = 'toto /app/blah titi\nhuh/app/ttt wew';
```

and my pattern is: `/app/something` I want to get as output in an array: `/app/blah` and `/app/ttt`.

(which is basically what `grep -E -o '\/app\/[a-z]*'` does)

I can't get it work !
I tried:

```
my $content = 'toto /app/blah titi\nhuh/app/ttt wew';
$content =~ m/(\/app\/[a-z]*)/;
print "Group: $1 $2\n";
```

but this only prints: `/app/blah` (not `/app/ttt`)

and anyway, I don't know how to put the results in a table:

```
my (@table) = @_;
```

the table does not contain anything!

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [`/g`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlretut#Global_matching) modifier to make the regular expression return all the matches as a list:

```
@table = $content =~ m/(\/app\/[a-z]*)/g;
print "Group: @table\n";
```

Also, [`@_`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#@ARG) does not have anything to do with regular expressions. Rather, it is the list of parameters that was passed to the current subroutine.

Comment: And from the command line you want: `[ "$(printf 'a0 b1\nc2 a3\n' | perl -ne 'print m/a./g')" = "a0a3" ] || exit 1`

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a one liner for some quick bash scripting where Perl would play one part, this worked for me:

```
$ echo foo000bar000baz | perl -ne 'for(m/(foo)|(baz)/g){ if ($_ ne "") { print "$_\n"}}'            
foo
baz
```

Works with multiline too

```
$ echo 'foo
> 123
> bar
> 456
> baz ' | perl -ne 'for(m/(foo)|(baz)/g){ if ($_ ne "") { print "$_\n"}}'
foo
baz
```

Explanation (Forgive and correct my mistakes as I'm not advanced level at Perl):

`STDIN` piped to `perl` : Could be anything, like `cat $file`

1. `m/Regular Expression within parenthesis indicating capture group/g`
2. Make `for loop` from matches above
3. Print `if` match is not `""` (empty)